# Unable to open website in WebView, it is blocked

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to access this url in an Android WebView: https://www.tokopedia.com/

I am not able to, I just get the message: Blocked WebView

Is there any way around this?

I have set

```
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
```

Comment: Try changing the user-agent.

Comment: @GabeSechan can you recommend a user agent for me to try?